# Programatically added fee in WooCommerce not being taxed

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have added the following to create additional cart fees for surcharges based on weight, but tax isn’t being applied to the additional fees – what am I missing?

The site in question is  http://oldhousestore.co.uk/

**CODE CREATED**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'shipping_weight_fee', 30, 1 );
function shipping_weight_fee( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Convert cart weight in grams
    $cart_weight = $cart->get_cart_contents_weight() * 1000;
    $fee = 0.00697; // Starting Fee below 1000g

    // Above
    if( $cart_weight > 1000 ){
        for( $i = 1000; $i < $cart_weight; $i += 1000 ){
            $fee +=0.00697;
        }
    }
    // Setting the calculated fee based on weight
    $cart->add_fee( __( 'Energy Surcharge' ), $fee, false );

    // Convert cart weight in grams
    $cart_weight = $cart->get_cart_contents_weight() * 1000;
    $fee = 0.00165; // Starting Fee below 1000g

    // Above
    if( $cart_weight > 1000 ){
        for( $i = 1000; $i < $cart_weight; $i += 1000 ){
            $fee +=0.00165;
        }
    }
    // Setting the calculated fee based on weight
    $cart->add_fee( __( 'Environmental Surcharge' ), $fee, false );
}
```

**EXPECTED:** Tax total to include Surcharges, Cart Items and Shipping

**OBSERVED:** Tax total only includes Cart items and shipping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter for `add_fee` sets wether or not the fee is taxable:

[`WC_Cart::add_fee( $name, $amount, $taxable, $tax_class );`](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_cartadd_fee/)

You set this to false on this line:
`$cart->add_fee( __( 'Energy Surcharge' ), $fee, false );`

You should at least set this to true, and perhaps provide the name for the tax class.

Comment: Thanks very much - this was my first attempt at coding this type of thing - thought it would have been something simple.